# how to zip two lists of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists of tuples, for example:

```
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
b = [(1,'a'),(4,'b'),(7,'c')]
```

The first element of each tuple in a and b are matched, I want to get a list like this:

```
merged = [(1,2,3,'a'),(4,5,6,'b'),(7,8,9,'c')]
```

Perhaps I will have another list like:

```
c = [(1,'xx'),(4,'yy'),(7,'zz')]
```

and merge it to "merged" list later, I tried "zip" and "map" which are not right for this case.

Comment: Is it possible that `a` and `b` might be ordered differently, like `[(7,8,9),(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]` and `[(7,'c'),(1,'a'),(4,'b')]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def merge(a,b):
    for ax, (first, bx) in zip(a,b):
        if ax[0] != first:
            raise ValueError("Items don't match")
        yield ax + (bx,)

print list(merge(a,b))
print list(merge(merge(a,b),c))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
>>> b = [(1,'a'),(4,'b'),(7,'c')]
>>> 
>>> [x + (z,) for x, (y, z) in zip(a, b)]
[(1, 2, 3, 'a'), (4, 5, 6, 'b'), (7, 8, 9, 'c')]
```

to check if first elements actually match,

```
>>> [x + y[1:] for x, y in zip(a, b) if x[0] == y[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [a[i]+(k,) for i,(j, k) in enumerate(b)]
[(1, 2, 3, 'a'), (4, 5, 6, 'b'), (7, 8, 9, 'c')]
```

Using `timeit` this is the fastest of the posted solutions to return a merged list.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ (x,y,z,b[i][1]) for i,(x,y,z) in enumerate(a) if x == b[i][0] ]
```

This makes sure that the values are matched and then merged.